# print each word in new line with removing extra space in c programming

Tags: c

**My Source Code**

```
    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(str[i]!=' '){
            str2[j]=str[i];
            flag=1;
        }

        if(flag==1 && str2[j]!=' ')
        {
           printf("\n");
           printf("%c",str2[j]);

           flag=0;
        }
    }
```

**My Output:**

```
I am      joe

I
a
m
j
o
e
```

But I want output like this:

```
I 
am
joe
```

I want each of the word prints in new line like `I` in one line `am` in another line and `joe` in another line also need to remove extra space before `joe`

Comment: Step through the code line by line with a debugger and the error should be pretty obvious.

Comment: sorry i tried but I can't track the error..

Comment: Please Provide Complete Code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,when you program parse the 'a' of your input"I am     joe",the first if statement make str2[j] is 'a' and flag is 1,so the next if condition of course be true,then the printf do the job,print newline and the 'a';

```
char str[100] = "I am      joe";
char str2[100] = {0};
int i,j;

/*flag means alread replace space to newline,so ignore continuous space*/
int flag = 0;

for(i=0, j=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
{   
    if(str[i] ==' '){
        if(flag != 1){ 
            str2[j++] = '\n';
            flag = 1;
        }   
    }   
    else{
        str2[j++] = str[i];
        if(flag == 1){ 
            flag = 0;
        }   
    }   

}   

printf("%s\n", str2);
return 0;
```

You should learn how to use a debug tools like GDB.

Comment: I am unable to understand your answer , can you explain it to me ? , Your wording confuses me and may confuse future reader of your answer , as yours is the selected answer , kindly please edit your answer to point wise , explain what you mean .

Comment: @Suraj Jain which part of the answer confuse you?

Answer (score 2):

I found it easier to just replace the space characters by new lines

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char str[] = "I am joe";

  for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if(str[i] == ' ')
      str[i] = '\n';
  }

  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

All you have to figure out is how to trim those extra spaces....

Comment: Awesome. Creativity.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the Gabriele Method , but if you do not want to put new line character instead of space, you could well do this .

Here we are having only one loop and wherever we see space we are printing newline else printing the character of string and loop continues till `i` reaches the value when `str[i]='\0'`, then the loop stops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int i = 0;
  char str[] = "I am joe";

  while (str[i] != '\0') {

    if (str[i] == ' ')     
      printf("\n");

    else
      printf("%c", str[i]);

    i++;

  }

}
```

Comment: When answering here you should format your code correctly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz is it ok ?

Comment: Better, but still not consistent.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Can you edit it , i will see what i am missing and will do so in future , i intend my code like this only.

Comment: I've edited your code. The problem was the indentation which was not consistent before my edit. BTW instead of `32` you can write `' '` which is more readable and shows directly your intention; and then you don't need the comment either. Rule of thumb: don't use "magic" numbers.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Done. Thankx

Comment: @MichaelWalz Atleast you did not downvoted , i have faced multiple times here person downvotes a post , olaf a person downvoted most of my post without reason.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Do you know tml?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134053/discussion-between-michael-walz-and-suraj-jain).